# string.join() in select

Tags: c#, linq

how to use

```
string.join(", ",)
```

inside select in a linq query

it gives error as
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

```
'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])'
```

Comment: The `string.Join` operation is not easily translated to SQL, so you can't use it in LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  As the error message states, LINQ to Entities doesn't support string.join.  However, there may be a work around depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible only after results are enumerated, call it ToList() and then use String.Join

i.e.

```
var result = db.Person
.Include("Occupations")
.ToList()
.Select(q=> new {
   Name = q.Name,
   Occupations = string.Join(", ", q.Occupations.Select(x=>x.Name))
});
```